# SailsJS not updating

Tags: npm, sails.js

I haven't used `sails` in a long while and was about to start a new project but wanted to update my older 0.12.14 version to 1.0.2. I first tried doing

`$ npm update -g`

and then running

`$ sails -v`

This returned

`0.12.14`

Confused, I listed the `npm` global packages

`$ npm list -g --depth=0`

and this returned the list of global packages without `sails`.

I tried

`$ npm uninstall sails -g`

and when running

`$ sails -v`

or even

`$ sails new test`

it appeared to continue working. Checking the version in the `package.json` of the test project revealed that the old version was still alive and kicking. I'm out of ideas on how to update / uninstall `sails`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update Sails.JS, use `npm install sails -g` instead of `npm update -g`

If that isn't working, be sure to update to the latest npm & Node.JS:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

then

```
sudo npm install sails -g
```

To manually download and install Node.JS: https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: `$ npm cache clean -f` seemed to have done the trick. Thanks!